# Android Studio states [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

I'm not quite sure how I would go about fixing this manifest. I have one activity with one fragment for reference, and this is just the manifest that was generated by Android Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Enayet.minigma" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The android documentation states that package names can contain both upper case and lower case letters, however, this issue seems to occur when using upper case.  Try changing your package name to

```
enayet.minigma
```